# VSTS - BoardColumn does not work in Queries

Tags: agile, scrum, azure-devops, kanban

In VSTS Online, using BoardColumn as a Query Criteria, or using it as a Column in Query Results, does not work.

For instance, we have custom columns, beginning with Committed, and progressing through additional states. It seems that the system only allows us to query using out-of-the-box column names, that match State values.

If I query for BoardColumn = Committed, the query returns Work Items that are in the Committed Column, or any of the subsequent columns, and the displayed value for BoardColumn in the query results simply says "Committed", because that is the State value on those Work Items.

Additionally, using one of the custom columns, such as "In QA", as a criteria value for Board Column, returns zero results, even though there are Work Items in that column.

This does not make sense. Why does the query functionality not actually look at the BoardColumn value when querying? Why does the query result display State instead of BoardColumn?

Comment: There is likely a problem with your query, as I query on custom board columns all the time and it works fine.

Comment: @DanielMann I tried this with BoardColumn as the only criteria, and the behavior is the same.

Comment: Update your question with the work item query you're running that's returning no results.

Comment: This is VSTS Online. It is a visual criteria editor. It is not a code window. The only criteria is Board Column = In QA

Comment: Then I don't know what to tell you -- I am looking at my instance of VSTS, in which I have a query that includes a board column clause, and it works fine.

Comment: Exactly. That is why I posted this. I am hoping this has happened to others, or perhaps is already documented somewhere. My searches came up empty.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue. The query result with custom columns is correct. Can you share some screenshot for your columns settings and query settings?

Comment: @PittsburghDBA Can you do me a favor and add the [Board Column] to a query (that does capture your user stories) using the Column options and then run a query and share the value of the [Board Column] field in the list? As with the other comments, this is working for me, but there are some interesting behaviours around which board owns the work item and can set the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few weeks ago I ran into an issue similar to this. We had our team split into two, and one of the new teams was using the Kanban board. For the split we used the information on [Visualstudio.com](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/scale/multiple-teams)

We noticed that, whilst the items were positioned in the correct board column, any queries would give the old state (i.e. Committed).

A hint to the problem was found on [visualstudio.uservoice.com](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/11721918-board-column-field-shows-the-wrong-value) where they were discussing which teams owns the item. Eventually I realized that, whilst our two new teams both had their own backlog iteration, so did the old 'root' team. Changing the Backlog Iteration path of the old team to some subiteration solved the problem for us. It seems the old team was still considered the owner.

The question seems to be: is your Work Item also visible on another Board? Then this might be the solution.

This is all TFS 2017 on-premises.

Comment: I too see this behaviour: If the team who owns the work item (i.e. team field in our case) moves the work item across columns, the board column value changes. Otherwise, it only reflects the original states in the "board column" dimension. If one isn't using the team field, it will likely be the area path that determines ownership of the work item.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that VSTS will save the board column information for the Team that "owns" the item. It's possible to move the item across different boards at different Team levels, but the query result reflects the team that owns the item. For example, if the item belongs to a Team's area, then it's placement on the board will be reflected in the query. The parent Team's placement on the board will not be reflected. This is true if you have nested teams/areas as well.

Answer (score 0):

when a team is configured the area and iteration path are mapped, if the team's area path includes the sub area paths and there is a seperate team configuration/board for one of the sub area path then you might see this.

you can exclude sub area paths from this team settings and doing so will have your workitem being mapped to a single area path which is mapped to a single team board.